# IpoptSolver has not been compiled as part of this binary

Tags: drake, ipopt

I have freshly installed drake using pip and while going through tutorials about mathematical programs, I cannot use the example with IpoptSolver. I am getting this error message, however, I cannot find information in the documentation how to compile it. Could you point me to the right direction?

`ValueError: IpoptSolver cannot Solve because IpoptSolver::available() is false, i.e., IpoptSolver has not been compiled as part of this binary. Refer to the IpoptSolver class overview documentation for how to compile it.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [pip install](https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html) instructions as of today, we see a link to [still has some known issues; see issue #15954](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15954)

Following that, we find a link to [Enable IPOPT in pip wheel #15971](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15971), an issue which was only resolved 4 hours ago.

So yes, in recent past, the IPOPT solver was not yet shipped in the pip wheels.  However, it *will* be included as of the [v0.39.0 release](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/16537) within the next day or two.  *(Edit: Drake v0.39.0 has been released, and has IPOPT available now.)*

In the meantime, possibly some other solver like NloptSolver or SnoptSolver would be able to solve the program.

The list of other solvers is here: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__solvers.html.